# Howto setup HSQLDB schema for Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, hsqldb

I'm writing a "simple" scheduler application which uses the great Quartz Scheduling framework.

Quartz works with most database systems (MySQL, Oracle, HSQLDB, ...), which just need to be specified in the quartz.properties config file. The database used must be initialized with the corresponding SQL init-script, which may be found in the Quartz installation's docs/dbTables directory.

Using a MySQL database, I just had to run the tables_mysql.sql script on the database and everything was fine.

Now I intend to switch to an in-memory DB (HSQLDB) running in file mode. Starting my app seems to create the HSQLDB correctly, but now I don't find an *easy* way to run the init-script on this database.

Checking Google and Stackoverflow I found some solutions, but they require either spring-framework, hibernate, Flyway or programmatically getting a connection and parsing/executing the statements in the init script.

My question: isn't there an easier way to set up an HSQLDB for Quartz? Ideally Quartz would do it by itself, since it knows the DB connection data from its config file as well as the required setup script... Am I missing something?

Thanks for any hints on this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlFile which is part of SqlTool. This is a separate jar, sqltool.jar, in the HSQLDB zip package.

This can be used with HSQLDB as well as other database engines.

The usage is covered in its own guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to get the schema file for your quartz version(tables_hsqldb.sql) and give the path of the schema file in application.properties file and then spring will create the schema on its own.Else you can place the schema file in resources folder. Then you need to inform the datasource to quartz so that quartz will take care of everything.